# Extract value from character array in R

Tags: regex, r

I have the following charecter array

```
 head(rest, n=20)
      [,1] [,2]   [,3] 
 [1,] ""   ""     ""   
 [2,] ""   ""     ""   
 [3,] "B"  "-1"   "-tv"
 [4,] ""   ""     ""   
 [5,] ""   ""     ""   
 [6,] "A"   ""     ""   
 [7,] ""   ""     ""   
...
[2893,] ""   ""    ""  
[2894,] ""   ""    ""  
[2895,] ""   ""    ""  
[2896,] "st" ""    ""  
[2897,] "2"  "-th" ""  
[2898,] "1"  ""    ""
```

I would like to extract the all capital letters, all numbers and all lower case letter while keeping the index values.

I can find all the capital *positions* letters with this

```
grep("[A-Z]", rest, perl=TRUE)
```

and the values with

```
grep("[A-Z]", rest, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

But I can't figure out how to return the value while keeping the index.

Comment: What would the result look like? A matrix with indices for a specific "group" (capital letters, numbers, lower case letters)?

Comment: I would like to get/append it to a data frame, where all capital letters is in one variable, all 2 word lower case are in another all the numbers in the last variable.

Comment: It sounds like you want to combine all strings-with-capitals into one column, all strings-with-lowercases into another column, and all strings-with-digits into another column, all appended to a data.frame. What do you want to happen if there are multiple strings of the same type in adjacent columns in the same row? For example, say in row 6 column 1 has `A` (which it does in your example) *and* column 2 has `B`? Would you want them to be concatenated? It it guaranteed that this will never happen? Please clarify your desired logic/output.

Comment: This should no be possible. Maybe I should explain what it is. It is the last section of a Danish address. The upper case letters are house Letter. Eg. 1A, 1B (I already isolated the house number), the lower case are which side on the floor. E.g. tv. is to the left. The number is the floor. So I just want a column with the house letter, one with the floor number and one with the side. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for (using your example data):

```
rest <- matrix(c('','','','','','','B','-1','-tv','','','','','','','A','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','st','','','2','-th','','1','',''),13,byrow=T);
pat <- c('[A-Z]','[0-9]','[a-z]');
name <- c('house','floor','side');
res <- setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(pat,function(x) { i <- grep(x,rest); x <- rep('',nrow(rest)); x[(i-1)%%nrow(rest)+1] <- rest[i]; x; }),stringsAsFactors=F),name);
res;
##    house floor side
## 1
## 2
## 3      B    -1  -tv
## 4
## 5
## 6      A
## 7
## 8
## 9
## 10
## 11               st
## 12           2  -th
## 13           1
```

Actually that's not a great demo because of a dearth of populated cells, here's some randomized data for another demo:

```
set.seed(9);
R <- 12;
C <- 3;
N <- 5;
rest <- matrix(sample(c(rstr(N,charset=letters,lmin=1,lmax=3),rstr(N,charset=LETTERS,lmin=1,lmax=3),rstr(N,charset=0:9,lmin=1,lmax=3),rep('',R*C-N*3))),R);
rest;
##       [,1]  [,2] [,3]
##  [1,] "AN"  ""   ""
##  [2,] "895" ""   ""
##  [3,] "698" ""   ""
##  [4,] "zd"  ""   "32"
##  [5,] ""    ""   ""
##  [6,] "CK"  ""   ""
##  [7,] ""    ""   ""
##  [8,] "JWZ" ""   "r"
##  [9,] "1"   "j"  "IX"
## [10,] ""    ""   "ZFM"
## [11,] "k"   "d"  ""
## [12,] ""    ""   "252"
pat <- c('[A-Z]','[0-9]','[a-z]');
name <- c('house','floor','side');
res <- setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(pat,function(x) { i <- grep(x,rest); x <- rep('',R); x[(i-1)%%R+1] <- rest[i]; x; }),stringsAsFactors=F),name);
res;
##    house floor side
## 1     AN
## 2          895
## 3          698
## 4           32   zd
## 5
## 6     CK
## 7
## 8    JWZ          r
## 9     IX     1    j
## 10   ZFM
## 11                d
## 12         252
```

Note that I used a little function I wrote called `rstr()` to produce the random string values. It's not relevant to this question so I haven't posted it, but if you want I can provide it as well in this answer.

By chance in row 11 there's a collision between two `side` values. You specified in the comments that this can't happen in your actual data, but you can see from the output that the code handles that case gracefully; it ends up keeping the rightmost value that was in the row.

---

The new requirement of moving *single-letter* lowercase strings from the third column to the first, concatenating with any existing value in the first column, can be satisfied thusly (continuing with my second demo):

```
res$house <- ifelse(nchar(res$side)==1,paste0(res$house,res$side),res$house);
res$side <- ifelse(nchar(res$side)==1,'',res$side);
res;
##    house floor side
## 1     AN
## 2          895
## 3          698
## 4           32   zd
## 5
## 6     CK
## 7
## 8   JWZr
## 9    IXj     1
## 10   ZFM
## 11     d
## 12         252
```

Comment: Is it possible to make so that if there are lower case single letter, they are put in the first column?

Comment: Do you mean you want to move *single-letter* lowercase strings from the third column to the first column, but leave *multiple-letter* lowercase strings sitting in the third column? Or do you just want to reorder the columns so that `side` is 1, `house` is 2, and `floor` is 3?

Comment: Do you mean you want to move single-letter lowercase strings from the third column to the first column, but leave multiple-letter lowercase strings sitting in the third column? - This is exactly what I want

Comment: What if there's already a `house` value sitting in the first column? In my second demo, for example, you can see `JWZ` is sitting where you want `r` to sit. What do you want to do with the `JWZ` value? Swap it to the third column? Discard it?

Comment: It should not be possible. But if there are two, they should be concatenated in the first column